# How to Upload Asset to Google Earth Engine from Google Drive/Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

As you know, there is a command line tool, *[earthengine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line)*,  one of which capabilities is that it allows you to upload images/tables to Google Earth Engine (**GEE**) from Google Cloud Storage (**GCS**):

```
earthengine upload image --asset_id=users/username/asset_id gs://bucket/image.tif
```

Unfortunately, *earthengine* does not support Google Drive (**GD**).

**My questions are:**

1. Is there any way to upload data from **GD** to **GEE** (not manually)?
2. What about uploading data (tfrecord, ...) directly from **Google Colab** to **GEE**?

*and yet another issue*,

3. When I try to "manually" upload tfrecord files images (xxxx.tfrecord + yyyy.json) from Colab to GEE using its asset UI, I get two kinds of errors:

   - when tfrecord and its json companion have the same name, i.e. xxxx=yyyy, and I select both of them, it says: "the file already been selected", and
   - when they have different names (or I select one of them), it says: "tfrecord files must have exactly one json file" or "every json file must have at least one tfrecord file",
   - after all the tricks, when the files are uploaded, it returns an error message saying: "Manifests for TfRecord ingestion must have exactly one tileset with exactly one source”.

***Any suggestions?***